# Probability of winning money with a pair of loaded dice

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution

You go gambling with a pair of loaded dice. Because of this, your odds of winning are 53% on every throw. Assuming the game pays 2:1 and you keep betting the same amount, how many games do you need to play to ensure an 80% likelihood of winning money?

I am lost with where to start on this problem. I would appreciate some help so I can figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Hi rdittmer, welcome to the site! As this is a self-study question, could you please add the `self-study` tag? Thank you.

Comment: Given OP's comment under the answer confirming the source of the question, I've added the self-study tag myself.

Comment: Start simply. What's the probability of coming out ahead on one game?

Comment: The probability of winning on any given throw is 53%.  What I am having trouble with is where does the payout come in and the likelihood of winning money?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a "self-study" problem.  Here are the hints for you:

1. Suppose you play N throws. What is the probability to win in exactly M throws?
2. How many throws you need to win money?

Comment: It's actually a homework question for a stats class.  The professor doesn't really teach anything and just advertises for his research lab for an hour twice a week.